# Convertendo String para Date e adiconando dias a uma data especifica.

Tags: javascript, jquery, data

Estou tentando fazer a soma de uma data com mais 30 dias, abaixo a forma de como estou tentando fazer:

```
  function validarContinuacaoCiclo(){
            var dataEmissaoGuia = $("#hiddenDataEmissaoGuia").val();
            var dataPrevistaAdministracao = $("#dataPrevistaAdministracaoTratamento").val();
            var dataEmissãoValidada = new Date(dataEmissaoGuia.getDate + 30);
```

}

Tentei fazer dessa forma tbm:

```
function validarContinuacaoCiclo(){
        var dataEmissaoGuia = $("#hiddenDataEmissaoGuia").val();
        var dataPrevistaAdministracao = $("#dataPrevistaAdministracaoTratamento").val();
        var dataEmissãoValidada = new Date(); 
        dataEmissãoValidada.setDate(dataEmissaoGuia.getDate() + 30);
}
```

Esou tomando erro de tipo de data inválida.Creio que o erro seja ao somar os dias com o meu atributo de data que esta vindo como **String**. 
Alguem pode me dizer uma forma de converter essa String em uma data do formato americano?
Ou há alguma forma diferente de se somar dias a uma data?

Answer (score 2):

Para manipulação de datas de forma consistente recomendo o Moment.js (http://momentjs.com/).

Se eu bem entendi sua pergunta, você pega a data de um campo texto. Vou assumir aqui que sua data está no formato brasileiro. Ex: 11/08/2014.

```js
function validarContinuacaoCiclo(){
  var dataEmissaoGuia = $("#hiddenDataEmissaoGuia").val();
  var dataPrevistaAdministracao = $("#dataPrevistaAdministracaoTratamento").val();

  // transforma o texto em um objeto data
  var dataEmissaoGuiaParseada = moment(dataEmissaoGuia, "DD/MM/YYYY");

  // adiciona 30 dias e retorna um objeto Date javascript
  var dataEmissãoValidada = dataEmissaoGuiaParseada.add('days', 30).toDate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado pela dica @agcorrea. Fiz de outra forma usando **Split**.Ele faz com que os valores separados pelo caracter que é definido na tag, virem arrays, assim fazendo com que seja possivel adicionar dias somente ao array que o desenvolvedor queira.

```
function validarContinuacaoCiclo(retorno){
        var dataEmissaoGuia = $("#hiddenDataEmissaoGuia").val().split('/');
        var dataPrevistaAdministracao = $("#dataPrevistaAdministracaoTratamento").val().split('/');
        var dataPrevistaAdministracaoArray = new Date(dataPrevistaAdministracao[2],dataPrevistaAdministracao[1],dataPrevistaAdministracao[0]);
        var dataEmissãoFormatadaArray = new Date(dataEmissaoGuia[2],dataEmissaoGuia[1],dataEmissaoGuia[0]);
        var cicloAtualQuimoterapia = $('#cicloAtualTratamentoQuimioterapia').val();
        var cicloAtualTratamentoQuimioterapiaCalculo = $('#cicloAtualTratamentoQuimioterapiaCalculo').val();

        dataEmissãoFormatadaArray.setDate(dataEmissãoFormatadaArray.getDate() + 30);
    //  var dataEmissaoValidada = dataEmissãoFormatadaArray.getDate() + '/' + dataEmissãoFormatadaArray.getMonth() + '/' + dataEmissãoFormatadaArray.getFullYear();
    //  var dataPrevistaAdministracaoFormatada = dataPrevistaAdministracaoArray.getDate() + '/' + dataPrevistaAdministracaoArray.getMonth() + '/' + dataPrevistaAdministracaoArray.getFullYear();
```